# Create own custom View without using XML

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I want to create a custom View which contains two buttons without using xml.

I tried this:

```
public class ZoomPlate extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;

    private Button plus;
    private Button minus;

    public ZoomPlate(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }

    public ZoomPlate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context;     

        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0);

        plus = new Button(context);
        plus.setText("Plus");
        plus.setLayoutParams(params);

        minus = new Button(context);
        minus.setText("Minus");
        minus.setLayoutParams(params);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        addView(plus);
        addView(minus);
    }
}
```

so that I can use the ZoomPlate in XML like a button or a textview like:

```
<at.bartinger.zoomplate.ZoomPlate
    android:id="@+id/zoomplate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

but when i try this nothing gets displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have something to do with whats set as your content view in your main Activity? Check here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29

Basically you have to set it from a layout resources or a View.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding your custom view to your XML layout? You need to use the full package name as in `<com.blabla.bla.ViewName android:properties="whatever" />`.

Comment: yes i know that how to write this in xml. The problem is the Viewobject